# Converting time between timezone without changing the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Our system currently defaults to Sydney time. I'm attempting to localize some reports to another timezone without changing the daily interval of the reports (i.e. 00:00:00 to 23:59:59).

Any time I attempt to convert the time object to another time zone it converts the hour/minutes/seconds along with the zone.

```
[16] pry(main)> t = Time.now
=> 2015-09-07 14:41:33 +1000

[17] pry(main)> t.in_time_zone("Darwin")
=> Mon, 07 Sep 2015 14:11:33 ACST +09:30
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get exact behavior you want but have a look at http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails to get idea how timezone works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Time::use_zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone) to override the time zone inside a given block:

```
t = Time.parse('2015-09-07 14:41:33 +1000')
#=> 2015-09-07 14:41:33 +1000

Time.use_zone('Darwin') { Time.zone.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec) }
#=> Mon, 07 Sep 2015 14:41:33 ACST +09:30
```

Or the shortcut:

```
Time.use_zone('Darwin') { Time.zone.local(*t) }
#=> Mon, 07 Sep 2015 14:41:33 ACST +09:30
```

`*t` converts `t` to an array (using [`Time#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Time.html#method-i-to_a)) and passes its elements as arguments:

> The ten elements can be passed directly to `::utc` or `::local` to create a new `Time` object.

Comment: This was helpful.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with regex is the most straightforward way:

```
t = Time.now
#=> 2015-09-07 05:53:23 +0000
Time.parse t.to_s.sub(/[+-]\d+$/, '+0930')
#=> 2015-09-07 05:53:23 +0930
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.. Please feel free to leave an any answers that would be better as I am still a lowly junior.

I created the following method:

```
def export_in_timezone(time, zone)
  Time.use_zone(zone) { time.to_datetime.change(offset: Time.zone.now.strftime("%z")) }
end
```

and pass in the time and timezone for each reporting being created.

Thanks!